# SAS - Add a Special Character to the Output

Tags: csv, file-io, sas

The task seems to be simple, but I keep getting an error when trying to get the following filename for my output: **filename_20170628112233*.csv**.

Note: having a * in the name is causing a problem, but I have to have it there.

My code is:

```
%let now=%sysfunc(datetime());
%let mydate=%sysfunc(putn(&now,B8601DN8))%sysfunc(timepart(&now),B8601TM6);

%let outfile=/...path.../filename_&mydate.*.csv;
```

Please help.

Comment: You cannot include the asterisk symbol in a file name. See the duplicate post I linked to. Therefore this is not a SAS issue but an OS or process issue.

Comment: This is what I wanted to confirm. Thank you, @Reeza!